# Notepad++ cut eveything before <a

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, text-editors, notepad

My Search result has hundreds of  textlines like

```
Line 333:   

<li id="menu-item-690" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-690"><a href="../Flatsome/wishlist/">Wishlist</a></li>
```

I want to delete everything before `<a` and after `/">` .. i.e. I want to keep only `href=""`  links.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Use the regex .*\.\. to select everything on the line up to the ..

Answer (score 1):

RegEx replace (in [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) for example):

- `(.*)(href="[^"]*")(.*)`

with

- `\2`